# How to add business intelligence to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, project, ssms, addition

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and SQL Server Management Studio 2012 also, but now I need to create new project in Visual Studio and that project (Integration Services) might be found under Business Intelligence, but the problem is next, I can't see Business Intelligence in my Visual studio, and after I did some research I've found next link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42313

But after I downloaded and tried to install this, it keeps showing me error popup..

> business intelligence for visual studio 2012 unspecified error

I dont know how to add this stuff to my Visual Studio and I really need it..
thanks guys